# jstl forToken with Nested HashMap in request Attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a HashMap (hshFields) of HashMaps (ecd_date, owned_by, etc..) with keys (label, size, etc..that I access as such:

```
<c:out value="${hshFields.ecd_date.label}" />
<c:out value="${hshFields.owned_by.label}" />
<c:out value="${hshFields.fnd_source.label}" />
```

(note: I must use JSTL and not EL)

the about spits out the a "label" of the field (maintained in an XML map)  i.e.:

```
commitment_id = Commitment Id 
owned_by = Commitement Owner
fndsource = Funding Source
```

I'd like to now use a jstl forToken to loop over the nested HashMap.  But I can not get it to work.  Here is one of my attempts:

```
 <c:forTokens items="commitment_id, owned_by, fndsource" delims="," var="curField">
    The Field Label is: <c:out value="${hshFields.${curField}.label}" /> <br />
    The Field Sixze is: <c:out value="${hshFields.${curField}.size}" /> <br />
</c:forTokens>
```

Is this not working because Of incorrect syntax or hopefully not because I don't have EL capability??

**EDIT**
OK based on skaffman's response below I have:

```
<c:forTokens items="owned_by, ecd_date, commitment_id" delims="," var="curField">
  Label for <c:out value="${curField}" /> : <c:out value="${hshFields[curField].label}" /><br></br>
</c:forTokens>
```

and the output is:

```
Label for owned_by : Commitment Owner
Label for ecd_date : 
Label for commitment_id :
```

It seems to be working only on the first token because if I use the following:

```
Label for owned_by : <c:out value="${hshFields.owned_by.label}" /> <br></br>
Label for ecd_date : <c:out value="${hshFields.ecd_date.label}" /> <br></br>
Label for commitment_id : <c:out value="${hshFields.commitment_id.label}" /> <br></br>
```

I get this output:

```
Label for owned_by : Commitment Owner
Label for ecd_date : Estimated Completion Date
Label for commitment_id : Commitment Number
```

Comment: Note: you **are** using *both* JSTL *and* EL. JSTL are those `<c:xxx>` tags, EL are those `${}` things.

Comment: @BalusC I mean I am using jsp 1.2 so this won't work: <input name="commitment_id" value="${commitmentItem.commitment_id}" /> but this does <input name="commitment_id" value="<c:out value="${commitmentItem.commitment_id}" />" />

Comment: That's called "EL in template text". It indeed doesn't work prior JSP 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right, it should be

```
<c:out value="${hshFields[curField].label}" />
```

rather than

```
<c:out value="${hshFields.${curField}.label}" />
```

Nested EL expressions like that isn't permitted.

**updated:** The reason it's only working for the first iteration in the loop is because you have spaces as well as commas in your `items` list, and the `delims` only handles the commas.  So change the loop to

```
items="commitment_id,owned_by,fndsource"
```

rather than

```
items="commitment_id, owned_by, fndsource"
```

Otherwise, the spaces will form part of the individual loop values.

Comment: Thanks. I made the change however, I am now only getting the label for my first token.  The succeeding ones spit out a blank.  I have edited my post above.